react / next.js Input file: initial selection not registering
I want upload files via html form using next.js (14) + nextui and everything seems to work fine except after reloading the page, the initial file selection is not registered. The event.target.files array is just empty
'use client'

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
    Button,
    Input,
    Modal,
    ModalContent,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalBody,
    Select,
    SelectItem,
    Textarea,
    useDisclosure
} from '@nextui-org/react';

function AlbumForm() {
    const [albumName, setAlbumName] = useState('');
    const [cover, setCover] = useState<File | null>(null);
    const [albumType, setAlbumType] = useState('');
    const [ageRating, setAgeRating] = useState('');
    const [titles, setTitles] = useState<File[]>([]);
    const {isOpen, onOpen, onClose} = useDisclosure();
    const [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);

    const handleTitleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log("Event triggered");
        const files = event.target.files;
        console.log(files)
        if (files && files.length > 20) {
            setFormError(true);
            showModal("You may upload a maximum of 20 files.");
            return;
        }
        let totalSize = 0;
        if (files) {
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                totalSize += files[i].size;
            }
            if (totalSize > 100 * 1024 * 1024) { // 100 MB
                setFormError(true);
                showModal("The uploaded filesize may not exceed 100 MB.");
                return;
            }
        }

        setTitles(files ? Array.from(files) : []);
        setFormError(false);
    };

    const showModal = (message: string) => {
        setResponseMessage(message);
        onOpen();
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!albumName) {
            setErrorMessage('Please provide an album name.');
            return;
        }

        if (formError) {
            showModal('Something went wrong...');
            return;
        }

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('albumName', albumName);
        if (cover) {
            formData.append('cover', cover);
        }
        formData.append('albumType', albumType);
        formData.append('ageRating', ageRating);
        for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            formData.append('titles', titles[i]);
        }

        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://my.api/endpoint', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });

            const responseData = await response.json();
            showModal(JSON.stringify(responseData));
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            showModal('Something went wrong...');
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => handleSubmit(e)}>
            <Input
                isClearable
                fullWidth
                color="primary"
                size="lg"
                placeholder="Album name"
                value={albumName}
                onChange={(e) => setAlbumName(e.target.value)}
            />
            {errorMessage && (
                <p style={{color: 'red', marginTop: '5px', fontSize: '14px'}}>
                    {errorMessage}
                </p>
            )}
            <Input
                type="file"
                name="cover"
                accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif"
                onChange={(e) => setCover(e.target.files?.[0] ?? null)}
            />
            <Select
                placeholder="Choose an album type"
                onChange={(e) => setAlbumType(e.target.value)}
                required
            >
                <SelectItem value="studio" key="a1">Studio</SelectItem>
                <SelectItem value="live" key="a2">Live</SelectItem>
                <SelectItem value="compilation" key="a3">Compilation</SelectItem>
            </Select>
            <Select
                placeholder="Choose an age rating"
                onChange={(e) => setAgeRating(e.target.value)}
                required
            >
                <SelectItem value="all" key="b1">All</SelectItem>
                <SelectItem value="adults" key="b2">Adults</SelectItem>
            </Select>
            <Input
                type="file"
                name="titles"
                accept=".mp3,.wav,.m4a"
                multiple
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => handleTitleChange(e)}
            />
            <Button type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
            <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} placement="center">
                <ModalContent>
                    {(onClose) => (
                        <>
                            <ModalHeader>
                                <p>Whoops...</p>
                            </ModalHeader>
                            <ModalBody>
                                <Textarea readOnly value={responseMessage} />
                            </ModalBody>
                        </>
                    )}
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal>
        </form>
    );
}
export default AlbumForm;


It's the same behavior for the single file upload and the multiple file upload. The error even occurs on both input element separately.
I tried the useRef-hook and as suggested in this question, but it didn't work either.
I guess it has something to do with the useState-hook, but I cannot figure it out.
